# SQL query for column numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with information like :

[image]

With these 2 columns I need to pull a column like "New Column" which is basically serial numbers of pages for each order.

I tried `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Page) AS NewColumn`

But that serialized the whole column and did not consider OrderNumber.

Comment: You need partition clause - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the partition

```
OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNumber ORDER BY Page)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select ordernumber,page,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ordernumber order by page) newcolumn from yourtable
```